# Convergence/divergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n \ln n}$. Is my proof ok?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

I have to study the convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{(n \ln n)}$
I know that if $a_n \ge 0$ and decreasing then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is of the same kind than $\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^ka_{2^k}$

Thus, i substitute and i get:
$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{2^k}{(2^k \ln 2^k)} =\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{( \ln 2^k)} =\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{( k \ln 2)}$ and i know this diverges becouse it is like $\sum 1/n$, and becouse of that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{(n \ln n)}$ diverges too.

I would appreciate your help thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is OK, by the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test): your initial series is divergent as is the harmonic series :
$$\displaystyle \sum_{n\geq2} \dfrac1n.$$

Comment: Ok tahnks a lot, the Cauchy condensation test would be "$a_n \ge 0$ and decreasing then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is of the same kind than $\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^ka_{2^k}$" ?? I have it in my book but without that refference name.

Comment: @Valentin It is the same. You are welcome!

Comment: @Valentin Just a thought, the integral test also works, because the anti derivative can be easily established.

Comment: I first looked on the web to see if what i have done was writgh, and in the websites that this problem was solved, it was solved by the "integral test", it seems to be usefull but i havent seen it on college yet. Thanks for your answer